# BeautifulSoup remove tag using replace caused 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Situation**

I'm trying to get the word `Non-Compliant` in [here](https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode=7164).

Thinking by easily using `replace()` will solve my aim, but it is actually giving me the error:

> 'NoneType' object is not callable

**Here is my code :**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 '
}

mBizLink = requests.get(str('https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode=7164'), headers=header)
mBizParser = BeautifulSoup(mBizLink.text, 'html.parser') 

mBizSyariah = mBizParser.find('label', {'id' : 'ctl17_lbShariah'}).find('span')
mmBizSyariah = str(mBizSyariah)
mBizSyariah = mBizSyariah.replace('<span> ', '')
mBizSyariah = mBizSyariah.replace(' </span>', '')
print(mBizSyariah)
```

**Here is my urrent result :**

[image]

**Question**

How can I remove the `span` tag to get the text out of this tag?

Thanks!

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: don't replace anything, you want `mBizSyariah.text`

Comment: Hey @diggusbickus ! You should answer them and I can mark it as correct answer! Thanks, it's solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with `beautifulsoup` the easiest way to grab the text of a tag is `.text` or if you want to grab and modify (join and strip) [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

```
mBizSyariah.text #contains whitespaces

mBizSyariah.get_text(strip=True) #without additional whitespaces
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 '
}

mBizLink = requests.get(str('https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode=7164'), headers=header)
mBizParser = BeautifulSoup(mBizLink.text, 'html.parser') 

mBizParser.find('label', {'id' : 'ctl17_lbShariah'}).find('span').get_text(strip=True)
```

#### Output:

> 'Non-Compliant'